# How can I transform an XML file using the identity transform pattern, but only on a particular subtree?

Tags: xml, xslt

I would like to transform an XML file using the identity transform, along with a bunch of other templates to tweak things. But I only want to apply all of this to a particular subtree, and ignore the rest of the XML document. Is there a particular pattern I should use to do this? My first guess is to use modes, but I'd prefer to avoid that if I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So if I understand correctly, you want to perform the XSLT (based upon the identity transform) on a subtree of the input and omit everything outside of that subtree from the result?  If so, you could do this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="/path/to/subtree" />
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Other templates -->
</xsl:stylesheet>
```